# Example of group that doesn't admit a p-complement.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've this example. Let $H$ a finite, simple, non abelian group, $P$ a non abelian finite p-group and consider the direct product $G=H\times$$P$. Then $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$ is a p-group but $G$ is not p-nilpotent.

---

Now my question is: how can I verify that G doesn't admit a p-complement? If $K$$\vartriangleleft$ $G$ is a p-complement then $K$$\leq$$H$ (because the p-complement is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient is a p-group, that is $O^p(G)$$=$$K$) and from the simplicity of $H$ it follows that $H$$=$$K$. But how can I conclude now? Is it a correct way to procede? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you are choosing $p$ dividing order of $H$.

Comment: I suspect that when you say $p$-complement you really mean *normal* $p$-complement. For example, $S_3$ admits a $3$-complement, but not a normal $3$-complement, and it is not $3$-nilpotent.